# How do I configure github action when the script is an always running script?

Tags: python, github, yaml, discord.py, github-actions

this is my yml script

```
name: roBOT test

on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:

runs-on: ubuntu-latest
strategy:
  matrix:
    python-version: [3.8, 3.9]

timeout-minutes: 5

steps:
- uses: actions/checkout@v2
- name: Set up Python
  uses: actions/setup-python@v2
  with:
      python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}
- name: Install dependencies
  run: |
    python -m pip install --upgrade pip
    pip install flake8 pytest
    pip install -r requirements.txt --upgrade pip
- name: Lint with flake8
  run: |
    # stop the build if there are Python syntax errors or undefined names
    flake8 . --count --select=E9,F63,F7,F82 --show-source --statistics
    # exit-zero treats all errors as warnings. The GitHub editor is 127 chars wide
    flake8 . --count --exit-zero --max-complexity=10 --max-line-length=127 --statistics
- name: Test
  env:
      TOKEN: ${{ secrets.TOKEN }}
      MONGO: ${{ secrets.MONGO }}
  run: python main.py
```

The main.py is the script for a discord bot.

```
import discord
import os
from decouple import config
from discord import channel
import  requests
import json
from duckduckgo_search import ddg
import wikipedia as wiki
import urllib
import database
import quiz

db = database.Database()
client = discord.Client()
quiz = quiz.Quiz(client)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    # more elif blocks here


DISCORD_TOKEN=config('TOKEN')
client.run(DISCORD_TOKEN)
```

What I want from github actions is just a test that the main.py has been running successfully. But when my github action runs, it runs infinitely and then stops after 6 hours. What can I do to run the main.py in github actions and then pass the test if the script run was successful?

Comment: You could use a timeout for the workflow: [reference](https://github.community/t/limit-runtime/16364) and [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idtimeout-minutes).

Comment: @GuiFalourd I can do that. But that's not my aim. Doing that results in failed test (though my script is actually running)

Comment: Ok. In that case, wouldn't it be easier to configure this inside the python script? For example returning a success or a failed message through it to end its execution, allowing you to perform other steps on your gha workflow.

Comment: @GuiFalourd can you provide an insight on how to do that?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Python (at least the way you used it here). But what I thought was performing those test once, or during a specific period, then return an error or a success output depending on the scenario, to end the file execution and follow with your github workflow.